# Java override locale setting for specific locale

Tags: java, locale

I'm using `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(amount)` to format currency from a BigDecimal to a string. This works as expected the problem is that our main target is the dutch market and the default dutch formatting is strange.

Let me explain, when formatting -125 I get "€ 125-" for dutch (expected was "-€125"). Uk works as expected giving "-£125.50".

I could check if the locale is Dutch and then supply a pattern each time I want to format decimals. But I would prefer a solution that overrides the dutch formatting settings. I was thinking about something like the following:

```
Locale nlLocale = new Locale("nl", "NL");
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("nl", "NL")).setFormatPattern("€ #");
```

So that each time I use the dutch locale when formatting I get my custom format. Does a similar solution exists?

Comment: Why do you want to change the Dutch formatting? Won't you confuse them by choosing a non-standard formatting option (for the Dutch that is).

Comment: I'm used [close](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/libcore/java/text/OldNumberFormatTest.java.htm)  / [similair](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Helperclassforformatnumberandcurrency.htm)  classes for Swing GUI, you can be able to create own matrix for number as Fractions too

Comment: @Dunes the users expect a different format than java is providing for dutch (the minus symbol is expected to be infront of the nr, not behind). mKorbel, I thought about wrapping each call to format, this will be my last resort but I hope I can just override some settings for specific locales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside the question of whether that particular format is "correct" or not, the way to change the currency instance for the "nl" locale is to implement and configure a custom [`LocaleServiceProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html) for the number format service.  (The provider class needs to subclass [`NumberFormatProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/spi/NumberFormatProvider.html), but the superclass javadoc explains how to configure the provider.)

The provider needs to return a non-standard `NumberFormat` instance for the particular case you are concerned about, but (presumably) delegate to the default provider in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [applyPattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#applyPattern-java.lang.String-) method:

```
final DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
df.applyPattern("¤#,##0.##");
```

Comment: When using 'getCurrencyInstance' you create a new instance of the formatter. Hence you'll have to apply the specific pattern each time that you want to format. I want to set the format once and have it applied to all formatters that are returned by getCurrencyInstance