# Fixing Java Locale Error Peru

Tags: java, locale

related to this bug https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7028073 i need to fix the display of the currency format for PERU.

How can i change the properties for de locale of PE_es?

Currenctly the currency is shown as S/ but it should be "S/.".

Can i just replace the properties file? i am looking for a soluction in the jre instalation or the code. I have tried looking for the file without luck.

Java version is 1.7.0 _22 b11

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099073/java-override-locale-setting-for-specific-locale) can help?

Answer (score 0):

The bug you mentioned is already fixed in the version 8u34. However, starting tomorrow, there will be a new "bug" (until it is changed/fixed).

Starting Dic 15th, the Peruvian Symbol will be `S/` (without the dot).

Depending on which version of the JVM you currently have, you may (or may not) run into this problem. In case you currently have the last version, your only options might be:

1. Use a workaround for Peruvian Currency
2. Wait until they update the JVM with the change so you can update it.

Regarding the second point, you may also want to file a bug/change report (similar to the `bug_id 7028073`).

Source: [El Peruano (Article 2)](http://busquedas.elperuano.com.pe/normaslegales/ley-que-cambia-el-nombre-de-la-unidad-monetaria-de-nuevo-sol-ley-n-30381-1322623-1/) (Source is in Spanish).

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution for that is make a little function to make it manually:

```
public String getPeruvianCurrencyFormat(double value)
{
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    nf.setGroupingUsed(true);
    return "S/. " + nf.format(value);
}
```