# Changing DecimalFormatSymbols symbols for language in java sdk

Tags: java, decimalformat

I'm using a 3rd party software built in Java that displays numbers. This software is multilanguage and one of the languages that we use is Euskera (eu, eu_ES). Number format is shown wrong in this language (123,456.89 instead of 123.456,89).

Searching more in-depth and decompiling some classes I've seen that number formatting is done with `DecimalFormatSymbols` and `DecimalFormat` so I've made a `junit test` to see if the issue is from this 3rd party software or from java.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("eu");
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
String pattern = "#,###.##";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, decimalFormatSymbols);
String formatted = decimalFormat.format(1234567.89765);
assertEquals("1.234.567,9", formatted);
```

After running this test I've seen is Java who is formatting this way.

In one hand I've downloaded the last version of this 3rd party software because is open source and I could make a little workaround that worked. On the other hand, we use a version from 6 years ago that can't be upgraded because os system requirements and this version are in Sourceforge's CVS which I was unable to download.

Is there any way I can change the `grouping separator` and `decimal separator` for Euskera in Java level?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but it's a bit of a palaver. Essentially, you can create a custom NumberFormatProvider that does something different for eu_ES and delegates to the original provider for all other locales. You'll have to put it in a JAR with a META-INF/services/xxxx file and include it on the classpath.

See this question: [Java override locale setting for specific locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099073/java-override-locale-setting-for-specific-locale)

And more instructions here:

- [LocaleServiceProvider JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html)
- [Tutorial on the Java Extension Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/)